# change the background color of three textInputlayouts by using listener

Tags: java, android, textview, android-textinputlayout

I have three text input layouts in my activity, I apply a listener on them and it changes background color when I click on it .but need to click again if I want to click the other two .my question is that how I implement such type of logic that when it 1st clicked and I click on one of the other two, the first one clickable color disappear and 2nd one or third one clicked and its background color change and same for others

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.textViewLoseWeightSubtitle) {

                    if (mStateChanged) {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_after_click);
                        // mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        mStateChanged = false;
                        mFittedToned.setClickable(false);
                        mBuildMuscle.setClickable(false);

                    } else {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_outline_style);
                        //mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#363C60"));
                        mStateChanged = true;
                        mFittedToned.setClickable(true);
                        mBuildMuscle.setClickable(true);
                    }
                }
                if (v.getId() == R.id.textViewBuildMusclesSubtitle) {
                    if (mStateChanged) {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_after_click);
                        // mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        mStateChanged = false;
                        mLoseWgt.setClickable(false);
                        mFittedToned.setClickable(false);

                    } else {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_outline_style);
                        //mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#363C60"));
                        mStateChanged = true;
                        mLoseWgt.setClickable(true);
                        mFittedToned.setClickable(true);
                    }
                }
                if (v.getId() == R.id.textViewFittedAndTonedSubtitle) {
                    if (mStateChanged) {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_after_click);
                        // mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        mStateChanged = false;
                        mLoseWgt.setClickable(false);
                        mBuildMuscle.setClickable(false);

                    } else {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_outline_style);
                        //mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#363C60"));
                        mStateChanged = true;
                        mLoseWgt.setClickable(true);
                        mBuildMuscle.setClickable(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        mLoseWgt.setOnClickListener(listener);
        mBuildMuscle.setOnClickListener(listener);
        mFittedToned.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Post a screen pls

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `onFocusChangedListener()`. It gives a callback with a boolean which can be used to identify whether the current view is selected or not.

Declare it as:

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener listener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_after_click);
            // mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_outline_style);
            //mLoseWgt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#363C60"));
        }
    }
});
```

Set it as:

```
mLoseWgt.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
mBuildMuscle.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
mFittedToned.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
```

That's it. Your other code seems redundant. For EditText specific functions, you can typecast the view provided by `onFocusChange()`.